# better_player no funciona al instalar just_audio en flutter

Tags: android, flutter, video, audio, android-manifest

Tengo una aplicación en flutter que permite ver videos desde una URL mediante la librería better_player y escuchar una radio de igual manera desde una URL con just_audio. El problema es que con las actualizaciones de flutter y las librerías, ha dejado de funcionar la librería de better_player y esto solo es en Android, ya que en iOS funciona correctamente.

Debo indicar que funcionaba correctamente hace un par de años que se publicó la aplicación pero no entiendo por que cuando se elimina la librería de just_audio funciona correctamente.

Adjunto fracciones de código:

**Video en vivo con Better Player**

```
AspectRatio(
  aspectRatio: 16 / 6,
  child: BetterPlayer.network(
     "https://ecoteltv.streamseguro.com:5443/LiveApp/streams/streaming.m3u8",
     betterPlayerConfiguration: const BetterPlayerConfiguration(
       aspectRatio: 16 / 6,
       autoPlay: true,
     ),
  ),
)
```

**Audio en vivo con Just Audio**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:cadena_ecotel/configuration.dart';

class RadioScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RadioScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RadioScreen> createState() => _RadioScreenState();
}

class _RadioScreenState extends State<RadioScreen> {
  String url = 'https://radio.streamseguro.com/proxy/ecotelradio/stream';
  final player = AudioPlayer();

  bool playState = true;

  Icon radioPlay = const Icon(
    Icons.pause_circle,
    color: Colors.white,
  );

  Future initAudio() async {
    await player.setUrl(url);
    player.play();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAudio();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    player.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double heightDevice = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.white, //change your color here
        ),
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: linearGradient),
        ),
        // brightness: Brightness.dark,
        title: const Text(
          'Ecotel Radio',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("resources/images/body_radio.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                height: heightDevice / 2,
                child: radioAnimation,
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: linearGradient,
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(40.0))),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    // slider(),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            setState(() {
                              if (playState) {
                                player.stop();
                                playState = false;
                                radioPlay = const Icon(
                                  Icons.play_circle,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                );
                              } else {
                                player.play();
                                playState = true;
                                radioPlay = const Icon(
                                  Icons.pause_circle,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                );
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          icon: radioPlay,
                          iconSize: 100.0,
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ))
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cadena_ecotel">
    <!-- Start open Whatsapp -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    <!-- End open whatsapp -->

   <application
        android:label="cadena_ecotel"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```